# Why are artifacts built with tycho-buildtimestamp-jgit still named -SNAPSHOT?

Tags: tycho

We use *tycho-buildtimestamp-jgit* as explained in the [tycho wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reproducible_Version_Qualifiers) to create reproducible version qualifiers for bundles.

The bundle jars created in the *target/* directory are still named `bundle.name-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` even though the MANIFEST.MF already contains the generated version qualifier.

Why isn't SNAPSHOT replaced with the generated qualifier? How can the pom.xml be adjusted to include the generated version in the bundle file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every bundle built by Tycho has a Maven version and an OSGi/p2 version. Which one of the two versions you see depends on the context. E.g. in the `target/` folder, being a Maven concept, you will see the bundle jar with the Maven version.

If you aggregate the bundle into a p2 repository (with the packaging type `eclipse-repository`), you'll see the bundle jar with a file name that  includes the OSGi version.

Note that the tycho-buildtimestamp-jgit plugin only affects the OSGi version, i.e. the replacement of the `qualifier` literal. Maven's `SNAPSHOT` literal is never replaced by Tycho.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Is there a property that contains the OSGi/p2 version?

Comment: This would be a good, separate question. Like this, I doubt that anyone else will benefit from the answer. Hence, I keep it short: http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/build-qualifier-mojo.html

Comment: `${buildQualifier}` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!